# Something is preventing my submit button from functioning

Tags: javascript

I posted earlier regarding a different topic and want to thank all who helped me out. I've cleaned up my code pretty well (I think) but now when I click 'submit' nothing happens. I suspect the issue is regarding sending data with ajax but there is a problem with the way I've written things to send both text and radio data. Before posting this, I did do a thorough search to see if the question may have been answered in another's post but didn't find it - probably because I'm not astute enough with javascript to relate it to my own code. Anyway, here is a sample http://jsfiddle.net/J2yWQ/78/ If someone could find my issue I would really appreciate it.

```
function emailWarning() {
    var check = document.getElementById("check");
    check.className = 'show';
}

function validateEmail(xem) {
    var re = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/;
    return re.test(xem);
}

function postData() {
        email = 'email'+document.getElementById('email').value;
    var tt = validateEmail(email);
    if (tt == true) {
        xmlhttp.open('POST', 'payment.php', true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xmlhttp.send(myProps.join("&"));
    } else {


    emailWarning();

    }

}

    var myProps = [];

function insert() {
    try {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
        }


        myProps = [];

        function addProp(id) {
            var input = document.getElementById(id);
            if(!input) {
               input = document.forms[0][id];   
            }
            var value = encodeURIComponent(input.value);
            myProps.push(id + "=" + value);
        }

        addProp('child_name');
        addProp('age');
        addProp('hometown');
        addProp('boy_girl');
        addProp('first_name');
        addProp('last_name');
        addProp('email');
        addProp('address1');
        addProp('address2');
        addProp('city');
        addProp('state');
        addProp('zip');
        addProp('country');

        var flagInvalid = false;
        var tempArray = document.getElementsByClassName("required");
        for (var i = 0; i < tempArray.length; i++) {
            if (tempArray[i].value == "") {
                flagInvalid = true;


    break;
        }
    }

    if (flagInvalid == false) {
        postData();

    } else {

        var showValidationError = function(id) {
        var el = document.getElementById(id);
        if (el) {
            el.className = 'show';
        }
        else {
            alert('Missing element #' + id);
        }
    }

    showValidationError('log');
    for (var i = 1; i < 12; i++) {
        showValidationError('log' + i);
    }
}   

    } catch (e) {
        alert('An error occured in inert: ' + e);
    }

}
```

Comment: Your inline onclick handler returns false. This prevents other handlers from being triggered. I do not know whether this is by design.

Comment: In the line `<button type="submit" name="submit-button-paypal" onclick="insert(); return false;">SUBMIT</button>` you're always returning false. Your validation function should be handling the true/false.

Comment: If I removed return false; none of my warnings work. I've been fighting this for 2 days. I get the submit to work and it disables my warnings. I fix the warnings and can't submit.

Comment: It works fine in firefox too. The ajax submit takes place, it's just that nothing happens on the fiddle because there is no payment.php script. Your submit button is working.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/J2yWQ/80/ Try this fiddle, I added a confirmation message.

Comment: On the fiddle, it should give an Error 404 message when the php file is not present. I click submit and nothing happens. If I remove "return false;" my warnings no longer appear but then I do get the Error 404 meaning the data was sent.

Comment: The alert gets executed but I don't think the send is. I have it on my site and it's not advancing to payment.php.

Comment: It seems you are fundamentally misunderstanding what ajax is. The whole point of ajax is to be able to submit the form without redirecting the page, which is what is happening here. If you want to redirect, use [this](http://jsfiddle.net/J2yWQ/82/).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18529/discussion-between-ctviking-and-asad)

Comment: Tried your fiddle. First, now my email validate doesn't work. And second, once the form is filled out and I submit I get an error message.